# How do I calculate the overlap integral of H2?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, wavefunction, integration

I'm given a problem where I need to "evaluate the overlap integral for two 1s orbitals as a function of interatomic spacing, R".

This is what I think I *need* to do:

$$S = \int \psi^*_a (\vec{r})\psi_b (\vec{r}-\vec{R})dV$$

$\psi_a(\vec{r}) = \frac{a_0^{-3/2}}{\sqrt{\pi}}e^{-r/a_0}$, so
$$S=\frac{a_0^{-3}}{\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^\pi \int_0^{R'} e^{-r/a_0  - (r-R)/a_0}dRd\theta d\phi$$

But I'm unsure because I'm not familiar with the terminology "overlap integral". It feels totally foreign to me, but this is my best guess.

Comment: http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/60601/

Comment: So... *why* are you integrating over *R* instead of *r*?

Comment: @CosmasZachos because the question asks me to? - *as a function of interatomic spacing, R*

Comment: So the overlap is a function of R, so the integral should not be over the free variable, right? Have you computed the magnitude of the vector **r-R** ?

Comment: Wouldn't that just give me **$\vec{r}_2$**, the position of the other atom?

Comment: Of course. So you are asked to integrate our **r** to obtain a function of **R**. Choose your angular origins judiciously, given the special vector **R**.